# Error in effectfun and parres for Gibbs Area Interaction model

Tags: r, spatstat

I am using spatstat v.1.59-0 to build some point process models, but I am having problems with some of the validation tools, specifically `effectfun` and and the residual plot `parres`

The components of the model are `rings_pp` which consists of point locations for 52 archaeological sites, and `elev` which is a DEM converted to a `spatstat` pixel image. I am trying to evaluate the fit of a Gibbs point process model with an Area Interaction parameter (`AreaInter`) and `elev`

I fit the model to the data using the following code:
    `rr1 <- data.frame(r=seq(100, 2000, by=50)) 
p1 <- profilepl(rr1, AreaInter, rings_pp~elev, aic=T)
ppm5 <- as.ppm(p1)`

Everything seems to be working fine (e.g., other diagnostics show the model is a reasonable fit to the data) except when I try to use `effectfun` and `parres` to evaluate the effect of the elevation covariate, they wont work.

`parres` gives the error `Error in m[, d$relevant, drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long` When I traceback the error I get the following:

```
`> trace(parres(ppm5, "elev"))
Error in m[, d$relevant, drop = FALSE] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
> traceback()
4: effectFun.can(x)
3: effectFun(xxx)
2: parres(ppm5, "elev")
1: trace(parres(ppm5, "elev"))`
```

`effectfun` works when `se.fit=FALSE` but will not work when `se.fit=TRUE` and gives the following error: `Error in quadform(mm, vc) : ncol(x) == nrow(v) is not TRUE` When I traceback the error I get the following:

```
`> trace(plot(effectfun(ppm5, "elev", se.fit=T)))
Error in quadform(mm, vc) : ncol(x) == nrow(v) is not TRUE
> traceback()
8: stop(simpleError(msg, call = sys.call(-1)))
7: stopifnot(ncol(x) == nrow(v))
6: quadform(mm, vc)
5: predict.ppm(orig.model, locations = fakeloc, covariates = fakecov, 
   se = se.fit)
4: predict(orig.model, locations = fakeloc, covariates = fakecov, 
   se = se.fit)
3: effectfun(ppm5, "elev", se.fit = T)
2: plot(effectfun(ppm5, "elev", se.fit = T))
1: trace(plot(effectfun(ppm5, "elev", se.fit = T)))`
```

When I fit an inhomogeneous model `ppm1 <- ppm(rings_pp, ~elev)` both `effectfun` and `parres` work fine and show a good fit (though using the residual K function `Kres` suggest the model isn't accounting for clustering). So it seems to be something with how I've fit the Gibbs `AreaInter` model.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for a good question with many details. Can you either supply your data or try to recreate the problem with a simulated dataset or using one of the built in datasets? It's much easier to debug a problem which can be reproduced locally.

Comment: Hi Dr. Rubak. Thank you for your reply. I was unable to recreate the problem with one of the example datasets (bei), and I don't think it's possible to upload my data to stackoverflow. The DEM covariate is pretty large (380 mb). However, I would be happy to email you the data and the R script if that is okay with you.

Comment: If at all possible post a public link to e.g. Dropbox for anybody to download and test the example. I will not have time to run the code and debug it the next week or more, but I will probably get around to it sometime. I cannot receive 380 MB in an email. I think my limit is 10 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for a clear question.

This is a bug, which can be demonstrated by the simple example

```
fit <- ppm(cells ~ x, AreaInter(0.07))
plot(effectfun(fit, se.fit=TRUE))
plot(parres(fit))
```

I will investigate and fix it soon.

**Postscript:** this has now been fixed in the development version of `spatstat` (version `1.59-0.020`) available on [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat)

.

Comment: Hi Dr. Baddeley. Okay thanks so much! Your R book with Rubak and Turner is fantastic. Any plans for a 2nd edition?